# How id it technically possible for Windows to wake up a hibernated computer?

Tags: windows, acpi

Windows has many different reasons why it might wake up a system... the biggest that comes to mind is for Windows Update tasks... but my question is how this is even possible when (at least to my understanding) a hibernated computer is effectively the same as being off, but with its memory dumped to secondary storage. How can a computer that has its CPU not running be able to execute an OS command?

Comment: The most basic explaination is that the LAN device sends a ACPI signal to the CPU which turns itself on.

Answer (score 0):

Windows wakes up in designated times or with external intervention. It does not wake up by itself. When you tell Windows to wake up for Windows Update it just wakes up at the specified time, checks updates, installs them if there are any new updates, then sleeps again. It's not like "Windows is constantly polling Windows Update from sleep mode".

For the task of waking up at a designates time, or with external input, it is not a feature of Windows. This is handled by the motherboard of your computer, at hardware level. All motherboards on market support a power management standard that allows putting computer to sleep and waking up [as described here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface).

Comment: Indeed. This specific feature is called RTC Alarm.

Comment: My question is, though, how does Windows trigger the event? Task Scheduler may have an entry in it to wake the computer at a specific time, but how does it know to wake the computer at that time if windows isn't running at that point in time?

Comment: As I tried to explain, Task Scheduler does not wake the computer. Task Scheduler only creates an alarm to wake up the computer. This alarm is created at hardware level. In plan words, Windows tells BIOS "wake up at 7:00 pm." BIOS keeps track of the timer and wakes the computer up. BIOS is always running if you computer is powered.